# Autodesk Forge: extracting material names from the viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to extract a list of material names from the Forge viewer so I can display them, but I haven't been able to find a good way to do this. So far I'm able to pull the color/texture information from the renderProxy materials but the actual name isn't listed in the renderProxy. I've also tried model.viewer.getProperties(...) but the material name does not seem to be listed in the properties either. What's the most reliable way to get the material names?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "display" the materials, but I doubt there is a direct way to access material files from API.

One workaround would be to use the extractor code I posted in this article: [Forge SVF Extractor in Node.js](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-nodejs) (or use that node.js project: [forge-extractor](https://github.com/leefsmp/forge-extractor)), so you can get urls of the material files and use them in your app or download them, depending your workflow.

For example, you can see the result of the extracted file on my disk after running the extractor on the building model:

[image]

[image]

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your response! What I'm after is more simple than that. I'm looking for a mapping of the user defined material names to the render fragment material. I've tried looking at your rcdb example, where you list the materials types, but I haven't been able to find the user-defined material names (eg. "My Brick Material", or "special plastic 5", etc). My app uses the material names as a key to assign a specific property, so I hope there's a way to find this.

Comment: Those materials are accessible from each component properties, you can use viewer.model.getProperties(dbId, result) to get properties of a component. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this! I am finding this information on the component level but cannot figure out how to get the information for an individual fragment. I'm finding that each fragment in a component points to the same dbId. For example, Revit's standard window is made of two fragments, the window glass and the "sash." model.getProperties(..) gives me a list which includes "glass pane material" and "sash material" but I can't find which fragment is the sash and which is the window glass. I'm also worried that I will need to extract the material names differently for each family type.